# Remove isolated elements of a vector

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I have a vector of integers and I want to filter it by eliminating the components that are "isolated". 
What do I mean by "isolated"? those components that does not lie in an 4-neighbourhood of other component.
The components in the vector are ordered increasingly, and there are no repetitions.

For example if I have  `c(1,2,3,8,15,16,17)`  then I need to eliminate `8` because is not in a 4-neighbourhood of other element.

I've tried applying

```
   for (p in 1:(length(index)-2))
      if((index[p+1]>3+index[p])&(index[p+2]>3+index[p+1])){index[p+1]<-0}


    index<-index[index!=0]
```

where `index` is my vector of interest, but there's some problem with the logical condition.
Could you please give me some hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it with a combination of `outer` and `colSums`, i.e.

```
x[colSums(abs(outer(x, x, `-`)) >= 4) == length(x)-1]
#[1] 8
```

To eliminate the values, we can do,

```
i1 <- colSums(outer(x, x, FUN = function(i, j) abs(i - j) >= 4)) == length(x) - 1
x[!i1]
#[1]  1  2  3 15 16 17
```

where,

```
x <- c(1,2,3,8,15,16,17)
```

Answer (score 5):

We keep values where preceding or next difference is lower or equal to 4 :

```
v <- c(1,2,3,8,15,16,17)
v[c(FALSE, diff(v) <= 4) | c(diff(v) <= 4, FALSE)]
```

Comment: Neat, but since the vector is assumed to be ordered, you can even remove the `abs` :)